# Moving AndroidStudio project - gradle problems

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I'm attempting to move an AndroidStudio project from the default workspace location to another location (as part of moving this project to version control).

I'm new to AndroidStudio ( this is my first "real" project in it ) but when poking around the documentation I found that local.properties should be left out of version control, and so I got rid of that. That fixed my first errors when attempting to import.

However, now when I attempt to import the project from the new location, I get the following error:

```
The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)
```

This project was created just a few days ago in AndroidStudio, using AndroidStudio's default built-in gradle install. In fact, after selecting the project, but for importing it, I can see AndroidStudio is using it's built-in gradle:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/gradle
```

AndroidStudio has also disabled the "Use default gradle wrapper" setting.

I'm using AndroidStudio 1.0.2, on Mac OS X, 10.10.1

**NOTE:**
To explain why I'm moving my project, I started the project as an experiment, and it went well, so I made a new repo for it (private github for work), cloned it to where I do my real work, copied over my project to the local clone, and then attempted to import it to AndroidStudio.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out I hadn't copied over .gradle or .idea when I copied the project to the new location.